# Fit width of a div inside another div that has padding left and right

Tags: html, css, width

I have to divs. The div outside has left and right paddings. The div inside has a width of 100%, but these 100% do not include the padding left and right.
Example:

```html
<div style="width:200px; height: 300px; padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px; background-color:green">
 <div style="width:100%; height:300px; background-color:blue">
<div>
```

My goal is, that the blue div becomes as width as the green div.
I do not want to leave the 100% width for the blue and enter it in px to keep a responsive website.
Is there a HTML/CSS way?

Comment: Just curious why did you picked most complicated solution to accept, and it's also obviously mis-calculated the pixels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```html
<div style="width:200px; height: 300px; padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px; background-color:green">
 <div style="width: calc(100% + 35px); height:300px; background-color:blue; margin-left: -15px;">
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<div>` element is a block element, it occupies the entire space of its parent container by default, so you won't need `width:100%;` on the inner div.

In order to make it full width, you can set `margin:0 -15px;` (the same as `padding` values on the container).

```html
<div style="width:200px; height: 300px; padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px; background-color:green">
    <div style="margin:0 -15px; height:300px; background-color:blue">
<div>
```